# Kendo Grid Column with ngFor

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, ngfor

I've this code

```
   <kendo-grid-column title="{{localizationKeys.adempimenti.organizzazione.responsabile}}" field="addettiGrid">
                        <li *ngFor="let addetto of addettiGrid; let i=index">
                            <div>{{addetto}}</div>
                        </li>
                    </kendo-grid-column>
```

The problem is that the data is taken from "field"  and not to my ngFor.

How to fix this?

Comment: 1. Are you trying to create multiple columns using ngFor?
2. can you provide the interface to your "addettiGrid"?

Comment: did you manage to figure out how to dynamically set the "field" property in Kendo Grid for Angular? I want to have the fields dynamically set based on the data that I feed to the grid.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `ng-template` with the `kendoGridCellTemplate` directive inside the `kendo-grid-column` component to provide your own implementation of how the column will render.

An example is

```
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate column="column" let-dataItem let-columnIndex="columnIndex">
            <div> <a (click)="navigateToItem(dataItem);">{{ dataItem[column.field] }}</a></div>
</ng-template>
```

More info: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/templates/